# How can I open a certain file automatically when opening a project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio

in some of my Visual Studio projects I have a file named "info.txt"

When I open a project VS remembers the files from the last session and restores them.

Is it possible to change this so that nothing is restored from previous sessions when I open a project and instead only a single file like "info.txt" is opend automatically ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with my Visual Commander extension.

To [Prevent Visual Studio from remembering last opened files](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/extensions.html#NoOpenedFiles) you subscribe to DTE.Events.**SolutionEvents.BeforeClosing** and call **Window.CloseAllDocuments**.

To [Open a file from the solution directory on opening a solution](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/extensions.html#OnSolutionOpened) you subscribe to DTE.Events.**SolutionEvents.Opened** and call **DTE.ItemOperations.OpenFile**.